# Can't redirect users to custom URL after succesful login in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to redirect the users to a custom URL after a succesful login but it doesn't work. It keeps redirecting users to this dashboard page "/". I already deployed the website to the server so I can't clear the route cache with artisan.

Laravel version is 5.3.29

App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/my-profile';
    protected $redirectPath = '/my-profile';

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return '/my-profile';
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```

App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
        {
            return redirect('/my-profile');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I have read that there might be some problems with Laravel in [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17092) post. It says that there might be some problems with this file: /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUser.php, but this error was fixed in Laravel version 5.3.29, but I can see that it is fixed and 'returnTo' method should work.

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUser.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

trait RedirectsUsers
{
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        Log::info("RedirectsUsers");
        if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
            return $this->redirectTo();
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/homeeeee';
    }
}
```

And my routes file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/confirm-your-email', 'Auth\ConfirmEmailController@confirm_email');

Route::get('/confirm-email/{register_token}', 'Auth\ConfirmEmailController@index');

Route::get('/my-profile', ['as' => 'my-profile' , 'uses' => 'MyProfileController@show', 'userAlert' => null]);

Route::post('/my-profile/edit-about', 'MyProfileController@editAbout');

Route::post('/my-profile/edit-profile-picture', 'MyProfileController@editProfilePicture');

Route::get('/search/company', 'SearchController@searchCompany');

Route::get('/my-profile/add-job', 'MyProfileController@addJobPage');

Route::get('/my-profile/add-job/{id}', 'MyProfileController@addCompanyJobPage');

Route::post('/my-profile/add-a-job', 'MyProfileController@addJob');

Route::post('/my-profile/delete-job', 'MyProfileController@deleteJob');

Route::get('/users/{id}', ['as' => 'users', 'uses' => 'UserController@show']);

Route::get('/rate/user/{id}', ['as' => 'rate', 'uses' => 'RateController@showUserRate']);

Route::post('/rate/rate-user/{id}', 'RateController@rateUser');

Route::get('/invite-user-rate/{id}', 'RateController@showInviteUserToRateYou');

Route::post('/invite-rate/user/{id}', 'RateController@inviteUserToRateYou');

Route::get('/company/{id}', ['as' => 'company', 'uses' => 'CompanyController@show']);

Route::get('/rate/company/{id}', 'RateController@showCompanyRate');

Route::post('/rate/rate-company/{id}', 'RateController@rateCompany');

Route::get('/search/{page}/results/', 'SearchController@showSearchCompanies');

Route::get('/search/{page}/people/results', 'SearchController@showSearchPeople');

Route::get('/leave-a-rating/', 'SearchController@showLeaveARating');

Route::get('/invite', ['as' => 'invite', 'uses' => 'OtherAuthentificatedController@showInvite']);

Route::post('/email-invite', 'OtherAuthentificatedController@emailInvite');

Route::get('/contact', 'OtherController@showContact');

Route::post('/send-contact-email', 'OtherController@sendContact');

Route::get('/tyfcu', 'OtherController@thankYouForContactingUs');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run this command on your server for clear chache
if you want
php artisan cache:clear

and for redirecting you can redirect by this method
return Redirect::route('/my-profile');

think this might be help you